# How does react redux promise middleware send the resulting action to the dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn about middleware for promises through the react redux [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) but don't understand the `then` part below:

```
const vanillaPromise = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action.then !== 'function') {
    return next(action)
  }

  return Promise.resolve(action).then(store.dispatch)
}
```

How does the `then` know what to dispatch? The action wasn't passed in as an argument like

```
return Promise.resolve(action).then(function (action) {store.dispatch(action})
```

so I don't understand how dispatch receives the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I can help with this explanation.

lets look at what you are familiar with:

```
return Promise.resolve(action)
    .then(function (action) { store.dispatch(action)} )
```

You see this part:

```
function (action) { store.dispatch(action)}
```

That is just a function waiting to be passed the "action" property.

Now, when we look at what you are having issues wrapping your brain around is this:

```
return Promise.resolve(action)
  .then(store.dispatch) // <--- this part
```

the "dispatch" is just a function, and it is expecting, in this case, an argument. Most likely, an object - like so:

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'MY_ACTION_TYPE' })}
```

now, you "could" wrap it in a closure, like so, and it will look familiar:

```
.then( (action) => {
   store.dispatch(action)
})
```

but, do we really need to "wrap" it in an anonymous function? Not really, so we just can put: store.dispatch, and it is function "waiting" to be passed the argument from the return of the promise. think of it like this:

```
 var MultiplyByTwo = (x) => x * 2

 Promise.resolve(5).then(MultiplyByTwo) 
// see here, this function is gonna be called with the resolution with the 5
```

when we examine the function "MultipleByTwo" -- 
it has that familiar signature you know about: 
**(x) => x * 2**

If we just remove the function name, its the same thing:

```
Promise.resolve(5).then((x) => x * 2)
```

Note: You see that resolve(5) --> think of that resolve.then as a chain, or a "handoff". When we "resolve(5)", we are passing that value "5" onward into ".then". Now remember, that 5 value could be anything... a primitive, 5 in this case, an object {TYPE: "WHATEVER"}, a function etc.. it just hands off.. Like, "Hey '.then', here is my value...."

```
resolve(5).then(myfunction)
        |                ^
        |__>__>__>__>__>_|
```

It is important to understand that "myFunction" is this example above or in our multiplyByTwo or even that store.dispatch example.. they are ALL expecting a passing argument(s).

```
multiplyByTwo(x) <-- expecting one argument
```

or your function might not declare it within the function signature BUT it will inside the body, ala..

```
myFunction() {
   const args = Array.from(arguments) // we grab the arguments
}
```

or hoping for any number of arguments

```
myOtherFunction(...args)
```

But yes -- those functions ARE expecting some input from the resolution to act on. There might be cases you don't care about the returned value, if any, you just want to have some flow control... do this, "THEN" that..

I hope that was helpful and I hope I actually answered your question. If not, let me know.

Comment: thank you, I can see that it has to not require the closure to work. but based on what is this working? what is the javascript rule that says a specific argument is passed in without being declared as a parameter? is this something that #then does? it magically takes the resolved value of the object that called it and inserts it into its callback?

Comment: yes, let me update my answer explaining how ".then" works.